# 2d space dividing by m lines

Tags: algorithm

It has been years since I wrote any program... so I need your help and advice.

I looking for an general algorithm to solve following problem:

There is an flat (2d) space in form of rectangle, by given dimensions axb.
Divide the space with given m- lines that takes given n-lengths. 
Lines can meet in nodes but can not be more lines in one node then given k.

Here there is an example 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzJ4a.png

[image]

let's assume that i.e. n2 is equal to another n2 etc -i know that on the picture is not exactly

maybe you can recommend literature that help me to solve that problem?

Comment: I think the confusing part here is what you consider to be "lines".  When I first looked at your diagram, it appeared to contain 4 lines, because all of your labelled line segments happen to form straight lines from one side of the rectangle to another side.  Is that just coincidence?  For example, do n1, n2, and n4 in your diagram have to be co-linear, or could you for example rotate n2 a little clockwise and n1 a little counter clockwise to make a crooked path from the bottom side to the top side?

Comment: You are right. It is just coincidence or one of possible solutions I have made a new sketch.

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ouVRL.png

Comment: Let's simplify. How to divide a 2d space with given segments(lines).

Comment: The problem sounds interesting, but poorly described. Can I not use **all** the m lines? Can some lines divide the space in shape of a polygon which is **disconnected** from the other lines and the border? Can there be a line end with doesn't connect with anything? You need to have a clearer picture of the problem and describe it well to get any answer.

Comment: solution depends on the values of m and k. it wouldn't if the line segments were all of different length.

Comment: What is given? Define all terms. What is asked for? Now I see the only question - if we know some literature. It is **not** a question for SO.

Answer (score 0):

That is an Euclidean graph problem. In particular, that graph is a planar straight line graph.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_straight_line_graph

If you are looking for literature, Computational Geometry: An Introduction by Preparata and Shamos may helps you.

Good luck!